# Sharepoint get url of nested directory that file is located in using React

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

I need to redirect to the folder where a file is located in when someone clicks on a fileicon.
The folder structure might look like this: `const filePathNested = ${sharepointSiteURL}/shared documents/nestedDir/nestedDir2`

on icon click, this function should be triggered:
`const onIconClick = () => {window.open(filePath, '_blank'); }`

I have access to the itemId's and itemNames, how can I redirect to the nested folder?
What should the filePathNested variable look like?

Thanks in advance for any tips